# What's wrong with this mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join

Consider following two tables:

```
tag_names (tag_id, tag_name)
tag_links (tag_id, image_id)
```

An image can have multiple tags, I want to select all tags for a specific image id.
I am trying following query, but it doesnt seem to select correctly (selects only one row),  What is wrong with it?

```
SELECT tag_name
FROM tag_names
LEFT JOIN tag_links.tag_id = tag_names.tag_id
WHERE tag_links.image_id = $image_id
```

Edit: I'm using CodeIgniter Active record query, but I wrote in basic SQL format so that if someone is not fimiliar with CodeIgniter can help. However, this query works fine with simple mysql format (without using CodeIgniter) but strangely does not work with CodeIgniter, even there is no any problem with the syntax, it just selects one row.

Here is CodeIgniter Syntax:

```
$this->db->select('tag_name');
$this->db->from('tag_names');
$this->db->join('tag_links', 'tag_links.tag_id = tag_names.tag_id', 'left');
$this -> db -> where('tag_links.image_id', (int)$image_id);     
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I think that tag_links must  be left joined with tag_names, not tag_names with tag_links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tag_name
FROM tag_names
LEFT JOIN tag_links
ON tag_links.tag_id = tag_names.tag_id
WHERE tag_links.image_id = $image_id
```

IMHO you forgot to join table (properly with `ON` statement) you are using.

**EDIT:** I have 2 ideas how to get rid of the problem:

First:
Change the line with SELECT

```
$this->db->select('tag_names.tag_name');
```

Second:
Use select() function with complete query:

```
$this->db->select($query, false);
```

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

from: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I forgot to put ON here, but its not the problem. As i edited my post and mentioned that this query works fine with simple mysql syntax, but im tryin to use with CodeIgniter active record, which gives strange results.

Comment: Thanks really for putting up your energies to fix the problem. However, the problem was causing by my stupidness, I didnt notice that in my model function, i was returning `$query->row();`, instead of `$query->result();` This is because i had just copied code from my other function. but thanks for your time, im accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a syntax error (you forgot **tag_links** in JOIN clause). By the way in my opinion you don't need **LEFT JOIN** for this purpose otherwise you may get incorrect results.

```
SELECT tag_name
FROM 
    tag_names
    JOIN tag_links ON tag_links.tag_id = tag_names.tag_id
WHERE tag_links.image_id = $image_id
```

Comment: You're wrong about getting incorrect results because WHERE statement won't allow it.

Comment: @avall In theory yes. But it's not a good practice to rely on the code with accidental hacks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tag_names.tag_name
FROM tag_links
LEFT JOIN tag_names.tag_id = tag_links.tag_id
WHERE tag_links.image_id = $image_id
```

`tag_names` is only going to have single entry for a given ID, which means your query will return a single result. You need to primarily select from `tag_links` and then join the name of the tag on top of it, so you correctly select from the table with the multiple entries.